# OpenCV autocomplete in sublime text 2?

Tags: opencv, autocomplete, sublimetext2

I am very new to sublime text 2, and not sure if I am managing it properly. What I would basically like to to do, is have autocomplete capabilities for OpenCV calls/functions, while coding in sublime text 2. Is this possible? Have not had much luck google-fu'ing so far, and it would be a shame if sublime text 2 does not have this capability.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want one that autocompletes files and folders cos I know there is one available for that

Comment: @RachelGallen I would like an autocomplete for OpenCV functions/calls/members, etc. For example, if I have mat image, I would like image.resh to autocomplete to image.reshape().

Comment: have you tried GoSublime https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime i don't use openCV so i cant guarantee it'll work

Comment: If you are writing python OpenCV, [here is a small collection of snippets](https://github.com/bobbyleary/sublime-opencv-python-snippets)

Comment: @AGS Thanks - good to know! I will be doing python OpenCV soon, and will certainly use this, thanks for that! I am wondering if one exists for C++ OpenCV stuff though... Cheers.